# Quais passos para implementar SSL/TSL em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, amazon-aws

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em ASP.NET MVC e gostaria de saber quais são os processos necessários para implementar TSL/SSL.

Na verdade não tenho certeza se aqui é o melhor lugar para perguntar isso, mesmo assim, imagino que você possa ter feito esse processo antes.

Eu preciso implementar algo na camada de software ou se trata apenas de infra? Tenho um servidor Amazon EC2 com um Elastic IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eu preciso implementar algo na camada de software ou se trata apenas de infra?

Na verdade está tudo pronto. Você só precisa habilitar sua aplicação. Clique no arquivo de projeto da sua aplicação ASP.NET MVC e pressione <kbd>F4</kbd>. Deve aparecer uma tela assim:

[image: Project Properties]

Mude o campo **SSL Enabled** para **True**. Sua aplicação passará a ter duas URL's, sendo uma para o HTTPS e a outra para o HTTP.

O IIS Express instala um certificado digital para você. Como ele é auto-assinado, funciona bem enquanto você está desenvolvendo, mas qualquer acesso externo dará problema na validação.

[A configuração do SSL no IIS está aqui](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis).

Se comprar um certificado não é uma opção, você pode usar [o do Cloudflare, que é gratuito](https://www.cloudflare.com/). Basta transferir o controle do seu DNS para ele e configurar o SSL no painel do Cloudflare. Além de SSL, o Cloudflare também funciona como uma espécie de uma *cache* misturada com camada de segurança.